# Modify @Cacheable spring annotation to use a secondary cacheManager for writing values to cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am connecting to Google Cloud Platform memorystore Redis with Read replica enabled. It exposes 2 endpoints:

1. Primary for writing to Redis Cache
2. Read Replica for reading from Redis Cache

I have created 2 Cache managers to connect to these endpoints. Now using `@Cacheable` annotation I can only specify one cache manager at a time. I need to specify a specific Cache manager for reading from cache and another one to write to the cache. I figured, I need to extend the behavior of `@Cacheable` to add a secondary Cache manager which can be used to write to the primary endpoint.

Is it possible to do so in Spring and if so, what is the process to achieve this behavior. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.13/reference/html/integration.html#cache

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes I have gone through it. I could not find any info on how to enhance or modify the behavior of Cacheable

Comment: You have to implement your own CacheManager

Comment: Ok thanks @SimonMartinelli, so you are implying that inside the CacheManager I handle the logic to write using one connection and read using another?

Comment: Yes. You could also use CachePut as far as I understand. Simply experiment with the options

Comment: @RaviMishra did you endup finding something ? Or did you write your own Cacheable implementation ?

Comment: @Alexis, I was able to modify using the unless attribute inside the Cacheable annotation. Posted detailed steps in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I was able to modify the @Cacheable behavior:

1. Add `unless` attribute inside @Cacheable as follows:

`@Cacheable(unless="isReadReplicaEnabled") public Data getData()`

2. Create a new method annotated with `@CachePut` in new class to use new cache manager which connects to Primary redis instance,as below:

`@CachePut(cacheManager ="primaryCacheManager") public void writeToCache()`

3. Inside the method annotated with @Cacheable call the `writeToCache` method if the read replica is enabled:

`if(isReadReplicaEnabled()){ writeToCache(); }`

Comment: This looks so complex for what should be something provided out of the box. Your solution does indeed work but.. at what cost?
I will keep digging I'm pretty sure we can tell the connection factory to read and write to different endpoints.

Comment: @Alexis, you are right. This is complex but the reason is I was maintaining a legacy Spring boot app using `jedis-2.9.0` as the Redis client and it was not possible to do an upgrade to Lettuce or Reddison. Any modern Redis client supports the master slave in configuration itself.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/ReadFrom-Settings

With Lettuce (but probably others as well) you can set a flag `.readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA)`
The factory will cleverly fetch the slave / read replica from the `INFO` command and issue reads to it automatically.

Note that if you use AWS ElastiCache Redis, their `INFO` command only returns a slave's private IP that will be unreachable by your app..

The only solution is to create your own `LettuceConnectionFactory` with a `RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration` where you will be able to set your master and replica node.

You won't be able to use the Spring's  auto `LettuceConnectionConfiguration` because they don't create `RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration` in there.